# Pandas dataframe manipulation to summarize days until certain status appears

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most efficient way to transforme this dataframe:

```
date         transaction_ids  id              status   
2020-01-01                00   1            approved
2020-02-01                00   1            approved
2020-03-01                25   1         disapproved
2020-03-08                33   1   trying_to_approve
2020-03-21                25   1         disapproved
2020-03-22                00   1            approved
2020-04-01                00   1            approved
2020-01-01                00   2            approved
2020-02-01                25   2         disapproved
2020-03-01                25   2         disapproved
2020-04-01                25   2         disapproved
```

To this onde:

```
id      status      days_until_approve    transaction_ids_not_approved    total_transaction_ids
 1    approved                      21                    [25, 33, 25]                        3
```

Where days_until_approve is the time, in days, between (2020-03-01), which is the first disapproved for id 1 and (2020-03-22), the first approved  (`00`) after the disapproved.

Comment: How do you calculate `days_until_approve`?

Comment: @jcaliz I believe the OP is calculating it by the difference between a `disapproved` and the next `approved`: the difference between index 2 (2020-03-01), which is the first disapproved for id 1, and index 5 (2020-03-22), which is the first approved after the disapproved

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use `groupby` and define your own function for each of the parameters:

```
#make sure date is a datetime object
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def fun(df):
    r = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['status', 'days_until_approve',
                                'transaction_ids_not_approved', 
                                'total_transaction_ids'])
    id = df.id.max()

    r.loc[id, :] = None
    r.loc[id,'status'] = df.query('date == date.max()').status.iloc[0]

    first_disapproved = df[df.status != 'approved'].index[0]
    next_approve = df[(df.status == 'approved') & 
                      (df.index > first_disapproved) ]


    if(next_approve.empty is False):
        next_approve = next_approve.index[0]
        r.loc[id,'days_until_approve'] = (df.iloc[next_approve].date -
                                      df.iloc[first_disapproved].date).days
    else:
        r.loc[id,'days_until_approve'] = None

    r.loc[id,'transaction_ids_not_approved'] = df.query(
            'status != "approved"'
        ).transaction_ids.to_list()

    r.loc[id,'total_transaction_ids'] = df.transaction_ids.nunique()
    return r


t.head()


#       status      days_until_approve  transaction_ids_not_approved   total_transaction_ids
#  id               
#  1    approved    21                   [25, 33, 25]                  3    
#  2    disapproved None                 [25, 25, 25]                  2
```

Comment: The function raise an error because I found some users without the approved status in the end... I rewrite the question with correct example.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Create New Dataframe to populate
column_names = ['id','status','days_until_approve','transaction_ids_not_approved','total_transaction_ids']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

for id, group in df.groupby('id'):
    # Set Values for New Dataframe
    new_df.at[id, 'total_transaction_ids'] = group['transaction_ids'].nunique()
    new_df.at[id, 'id'] = id
    new_df.at[id, 'status'] = 'approved' if (group['status'].isin(['approved']) ).any() else 'not approved'

    # Find Transaction Ids that were never approved
    t_ids = group['transaction_ids'].unique()
    not_approved = [ str(i) for i in t_ids if ((group['transaction_ids']==i) & (~group['status'].isin(['approved'])) ).any()]
    new_df.at[id, 'transaction_ids_not_approved'] = ','.join(not_approved)

    # Find number of days it took to approve for each ID group
    first_rows_dis = [i for i, row in group.iterrows() if row['status'] == 'disapproved' and ( (group.index> i) & (group['status'].isin(['approved'])) ).any() ]

    if first_rows_dis:   
        first_row = min(first_rows_dis)
        first_disapproved_date = group.loc[first_row, 'date']
        first_approved_date =  group.loc[ (group.index> first_row) & (group['status'].isin(['approved'])),"date"].min()
        diff_days = (first_approved_date - first_disapproved_date).days

        new_df.at[id, 'days_until_approve'] = diff_days

    else:
        new_df.at[id, 'days_until_approve'] = None
```

Output:

```
id  status  days_until_approve  transaction_ids_not_approved    total_transaction_ids
1   approved    21                    25,33                          3
2   approved    None                    25                           2
```